# Expected begin_object but was string at line 1 column 1

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application,In that,I have a task to update profile image when I am try to update image I am getting that error,I don't know what is the root cause of that error please help me how to fix that.

My log is below

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
            at com.ringee.app.ImageUploadActivity$5$2.doInBackground(ImageUploadActivity.java:215)
            at com.ringee.app.ImageUploadActivity$5$2.doInBackground(ImageUploadActivity.java:206)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:387)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:189)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
            at com.ringee.app.ImageUploadActivity$5$2.doInBackground(ImageUploadActivity.java:215)
            at com.ringee.app.ImageUploadActivity$5$2.doInBackground(ImageUploadActivity.java:206)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

My code is below

```
{
                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                            MediaMO mediaMO1 = new MediaMO();
                            mediaMO1.setRingeeUserId(userMO.getRingeeUserId());
                            mediaMO1.setIsType(Constants.IS_TYPE_PROFILE_IMAGE);
                            String mediaMo = mediaDelegates.updateFileToServer(mediaMO1, context, imgFile);
                            // String mediaMo = mediaDelegates.updateFileToServer(mediaMO, context, imgFile);
                            if (!mediaMo.equals("null")) {
                            //I am getting that error here
                                mediaMO = gson.fromJson(mediaMo, new TypeToken<MediaMO>() {
                                }.getType());

                                try {
                                    URL url = new URL(mediaMO.getFileSrcLink());
                                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                                    connection.connect();
                                    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                                    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Log.i(Constants.TAG, e.toString());
                                }
                            }
                            Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_action_user);
                            return largeIcon;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap myBitmap) {
                            prgDialog.cancel();
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                        }
                    }.execute(null, null, null);
                }
```

my json is

```
    {"UserId":1,"mediaId":0,"isType":1,"isDelete":0}
```

Comment: Your JSON is not an JSON object. Please post the json you get and try to parse.

Comment: the json you are parsing is validated? is it in proper json format?

Comment: i am added my json response please check it

Comment: @Thomas.did u check my json response